# CMS SPIP, how to updated the file inside Squelettes directory

Tags: upload, spip

Heloo,
I have website that built by SPIP and already online on the internet. Since my webmaster dont work anymore with us, now I try to learning CMS SPIP.

I want to edit one of the html file, located inside this directory : httpdocs/squelettes/myfile.html. Say the name of my file is myfile.html

I changed some part of the file than upload it through fileZile. When I open my browser and refresh it, the file haven't changed yet. but it's successful upload.

please advise, do we need to configure something to upload the file.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to refresh a page in SPIP when you have caching issues : pressing the `Reprocess page` button on the public site (as said by Serge) or adding `?var_mode=recalcul` as a parameter of your URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the matter is in website cache. SPIP is hard caching HTML and images.
Try to clean cache via private area (under Maintenance button in SPIP 3) or press "Reprocess page" button on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

With your FTP connection go to the SPIP root directory, then find the `/tmp` directory open it and clear\empty the `/cache` directory inside it. This directory contains temporary files & cache files.